# Python autoscale with stepsize defined

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to plot the axis with autoscale with stepsize defined?

```
plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='y', step = 0.5)
```

Above does not work.

I have the following hardcoded but its not ideal. For different data input.

```
ymin = -2
ymax = 1.5
plt.ylim(ymin, ymax)
plt.yticks(np.arange(ymin, ymax, step = 0.5))
```

Thanks in advance